# Re-design for common anode instead of common cathode

Tags: power-supply, led, driver, rgb

I have a very simple circuit, and I want to use a tri-color LED to indicate which 1 of 3 outputs is on. I currently have a design that works for a common cathode 4-pin LED. However, I have easier AND cheaper access to this function of LED with a common anode.

It has to be red, yellow, and green. Each output has to drive a separate 10Ω resistor, exactly as shown in the pics. Only 1 output is on at a time.

The picture on the left is common cathode, and works as intended. How can you change the picture on the right (common anode), in order to acheive the same result?

[image]

Comment: In the right-hand drawing, you could place R5 and RYG just to the left of the Green, Yellow, and Red power sources... (With R5 to GND, and the cathodes to the - supply terminals.)  But maybe I'm misunderstanding something.

Comment: I am not able to physically connect anything to the negative side of the power supplies unfortunately.

Comment: If you're talking about connecting the cathodes to +, that will not inhibit current flow through the LEDs.

Answer (score 2):

You could do this (resistor only shown for one channel). You could use a single ULN2003A in place of all the transistors and all the resistors except for the 500R, and that is precisely what I would suggest doing.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f66J4n.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: I am going to avoid adding components to the design if I can. Thanks for this thought though. If I absolutely have to, I'll wait for the common cathode LEDs to hit stock.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use additional components then the only alternative I see is reversing the sources, assuming the load nature and what is shown as source allows this.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fYw8yf.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: With this, what keeps V1 electrons from going to V2 or V3?

Comment: @bretts The resistors. This has the same behaviour as the schematic you have posted. The source is just a voltage potential, it doesn't make a difference which polarity is common to the circuit.